# Laravel broadcasting channel function won't fire

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, pusher, laravel-broadcast

So I'm gonna use laravel broadcasting for a chat app,

I followed [Laravel Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting) approach,

- Uncommented `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider`
  from `providers` array inside `config/app.php`
- Registered in pusher website, made a channel
  and filled the fields below inside `.env` file with my pusher channel info

```
PUSHER_APP_ID
PUSHER_APP_KEY
PUSHER_APP_SECRET
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER
```

- Inside my `broadcast.php` config file where I set the default `driver` to `pusher`, I also added

```
'options' => [
    'cluster' => 'us2',
    'encrypted' => true,
],
```

to `pusher` array inside `connections` array based on my channel info in pusher panel

- Installed pusher php package on my laravel project using `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server "~3.0"` command

Here is my event class

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;
use App\User;
use App\TherapyMessage;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use App\AppLog;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;

class TherapyMessageSent implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * User that sent the message
     *
     * @var User
     */
    public $user;

    /**
     * Message details
     *
     * @var Message
     */
    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, TherapyMessage $message)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        $message_id = $this->message->id;
        $user = $this->user;

        AppLog::create([
            'file_name' => __FILE__,
            'message' => "broadcast before send with Message ID of $message_id from $user->full_name"
        ]);

        return new PrivateChannel("therapy-chat.$message_id");
    }
}
```

- The `AppLog` is a model that I use for logging inside the project
- I tried implementing `ShouldBroadcast` interface at first but that didn't work either
- I also registered my event inside `EventServiceProvider.php` file and run `php artisan event:generate` command, here is the `EventServiceProvider` `$listen` array:

```
protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        TherapyMessageSent::class
    ],
];
```

I also imported the event namespace next to other namespaces inside the file: 
`use \App\Events\TherapyMessageSent;`

Here is the channel that I defined inside `routes/channels.php` file:

```
use App\AppLog;

Broadcast::channel('therapy-chat.{message_id}', function ($user, $message_id) {

    AppLog::create([
        'file_name' => __FILE__,
        'message' => "broadcast sending with Message ID of $message_id to $user->full_name"
    ]);

    if (!Auth::check()) return false;

    $message = \App\TherapyMessage::find($message_id);

    if (!$message) {

        AppLog::create([
            'file_name' => __FILE__,
            'message' => "Message with ID of $message_id Not Found for broadcasting"
        ]);

        return false;
    }

    $will_send = false;

    if ($therapist = $user->therapist) {
        $will_send = $therapist->id === $message->therapist_id;
    } else if ($patient = $user->patient) {
        $will_send = $message->patient_id === $patient->id;
    }

    if ($will_send) {

        AppLog::create([
            'file_name' => __FILE__,
            'message' => "Message with ID of $message_id broadcasted to $user->full_name"
        ]);
    }

    return $will_send;
});
```

Finally, this is my controller method:

```
public function sendToTherapist(Request $request) {

    $validation = \Validator::make($request->all(), ['message' => 'required']);

    if ($validation->fails()) return $this->validationError($validation);

    $user = \Auth::user();
    $patient = $user->patient;
    $therapist = $patient->therapist;

    if (!$therapist) return $this->errorWithMessage('Patient does not have Therapist');

    $message = \App\TherapyMessage::create([
        'patient_id' => $patient->id,
        'therapist_id' => $therapist->id,
        'type' => TherapyMessageType::TEXT,
        'text' => $request->message,
        'sender_role' => TherapyMessageSenderRole::PATIENT
    ]);

    broadcast(new TherapyMessageSent($user, $message))->toOthers();

    return $this->success(['id' => $message->id]);
}
```

- My controller class extends from BaseController which is a custom controller class with helper methods such as `success()`, `validationError()` and `errorWithMessage()`

As you see in the code above
I filled `$user` and `$message` with correct values and the request works without any error

I think the channel method won't even be fired,
as I check the `AppLog` table when I call `broadcast` method, only the log inside `TherapyMessageSent` event `broadcastOn` function is saved
and even the log that I save at the beginning of `channels.php` method, isn't saved so I think this method is never executed.

If anyone could help me with the problem, I'd be thankful.

Comment: Is your queue worker running (`php artisan queue:work`)? [from docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#defining-broadcast-events): _"...Then, you only need to fire the event as you normally would. Once the event has been fired, a queued job will automatically broadcast the event over your specified broadcast driver."_

Comment: can you share the controller where you fire the TherapyMessageSent event ?

Comment: @senty Yes and the event fires as I mentioned, but when it calls `PrivateChannel("therapy-chat.$message_id");` the method inside the `channel.php` won't be fired, the logs that I save from `TherapyMessageSent` file will be created and I can see them from DB but the logs inside `channels.php` won't be saved, that's why I think the method inside `channel.php` won't even get executed

Comment: @AhmedAboud I just added my full controller method to the question

Comment: can you remove the toOthers and check if it returns any thing to you ( auth user with patient )

Comment: also follow https://laracasts.com/series/get-real-with-laravel-echo and https://laracasts.com/lessons/introducing-laravel-echo

Comment: @AhmedAboud I didn't get you exactly, remove `toOthers()` and check what `broadcast()` returns? if so, it returns an instance of `Illuminate\Broadcasting\PendingBroadcast` which when I try to convert it to string using `serialize()` or `eval()` to see the actual value it throws exception saying `Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed`, btw, does it matter what it returns?

Comment: queue driver default ?

Comment: you say its not working so it returns nothing ? also post your front end

Comment: @AhmedAboud queue driver is database, I think it's the default

Comment: @AhmedAboud I don't know if it returns nothing or not, I actually don't know how it works but all I see is the channel function won't execute

Comment: @AMINEDGE watch these series https://laracasts.com/series/get-real-with-laravel-echo https://laracasts.com/lessons/introducing-laravel-echo by taylor and jeffrey